# How to get user defined tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ado.net, user-defined-types

I am trying to narrow down which tables I get back from querying the schema. While I can get back all tables, I saw other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45811143/6085193), but they dont have info on getting user *back User Defined tables*, I would like to query and

1. get back, *user defined tables*
2. get back tables based on some criteria, for e.g. table with `tenantId` col

   ```
   public static List<string> GetUserCreatedTables(string connectionString = null)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
           connectionString = Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
           List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();
           foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
           {
               TableNames.Add(row[2].ToString().Trim());
           }
           return TableNames;
       }
   }
   ```

---

I am familiar with this method, where I can query directly.
`SELECT  Name from Sysobjects where xtype = 'u'` , but I would like to adopt the previous method so I can reuse it to query others.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible using GetSchema()

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks for that, on the msdn site it says its capable of taking a string argument linked to the schema, but does not tell me which string is linked to user defined tables.. so I was asking, lets wait and see if someone else has an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you pass *StructuredTypeMembers* rather than *Tables* to `GetSchema()` it will return the user defined table types and their columns.

To obtain a filtered list, you can pass in a restriction to `GetSchema()`. The restrictions for *StructuredTypeMembers* are *Catalog*, *Owner*, *Table* and *Column*. These are passed in an array, in that order, to the second parameter of `GetSchema()`.

To get the user defined tables with a column of *tenantId*, you can call `GetSchema()` as follows:

```
connection.GetSchema("StructuredTypeMembers", (new[] { null, null, null, "tenantId"}));
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I saw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/schema-restrictions after looking at your structured type members. How do I simply get all the `user created tables` (I can worry about tenantId later). When I tried onnection.GetSchema("StructuredTypeMembers") its giving me catalog owners, tables etc. with various restriction numbers...

Comment: The name of the user defined table is returned as `TYPE_NAME` (the database is in `TYPE_CATALOG` and the schema in `TYPE_SCHEMA`) in the DataTable returned by `GetSchema()`. A row is returned for each column in each user defined table, so you may need to remove duplicates if you need one entry per user defined table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SMO` objects to verify if the table is a user-created table and column names as well.  As noted below the `IsSystemObject` property returns true for system objects.  The `Contains` method of `Columns` can be used to check the column name.  References to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO` will needed to be added to the project with the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` namespace referenced.  To look at views change the `Table` object to a `View` one in the first `foreach` loop.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

            Server serv = new Server(@"YourServer");

            //for Windows authentication
            serv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
            serv.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 600;
            Database db = serv.Databases["YourDatabase"];

            List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();

            foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
            {
                //check for system objects
                if (!t.IsSystemObject && t.Columns.Contains("tenantId"))
                {
                    //use the Name property to return the table name
                    TableNames.Add(t.Name);
                }
            }
```